# OpenVPN Not passing traffic

Tags: openvpn

i installed OpenVPN using https://github.com/Angristan/OpenVPN-install but i'm not able to access the internet through it. It connects fine and some kilobytes pass according to the counter but i'm not able to browse the internet. The goal is to have an iPhone connect to the internet via the VPN. What else could i have missed?

Forwarding is on:

```
 % sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Masquerading is on (by setup script):

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere
```

OpenVPN lists the client as connected:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Sun Aug 26 18:54:09 2018
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
UNDEF,94.*.*.*:24174,108,66,Sun Aug 26 18:54:07 2018
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,1
END
```

server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_**********.crt
key server_**********.key
tls-auth tls-auth.key 0
dh dh.pem
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
duplicate-cn
```

client.ovpn:

```
client
proto tcp-client
remote my.dns.name 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_********** name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
***
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
***
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
***
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
***
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
***
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: What platform have you installed the server component on? What are the server's IP addresses? With the connection from the client established, can the client ping the server? On all its IP addresses? If not, what does the openvpn debug log say about the connection (both on client and server)?

Comment: It is on Ubuntu 18.04, Server ip is public with a "flexible public ip" on Digitalocean, this means eth0 has a public ip which might change in the future and there is another public ip routed to that ip which will not change. Clients connect to the "static/flexible" public ip. The client can ping the server on all 3 (10.8.0.1, and both public ip's) addresses with the VPN established.

Comment: Ok please add that to your question so it's easy for everyone to read